# How to create a column that has the same value per group in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I currently have a Pandas Dataframe with lots of stock tickers in my first column. They are time series so each Tickers appears more than once. In my second column I have a CUSIP code, but this code only appears in the row where the ticker appears first, all the next rows do not contain this CUSIP code. I would like to have this same CUSIP code in all the columns that match the same ticker. This is what my dataframe looks like, I want all the NaN to fill with the correct CUSIP so that you get the dataframe below

```
MSFT.OQ     594918104   FY2019  55252000000 United States   USA 1
MSFT.OQ     NaN         FY2018  44501000000 United States   USA 1
MSFT.OQ     NaN         FY2017  42730000000 United States   USA 1
MSFT.OQ     NaN         FY2016  25145000000 United States   USA 1
EFT_pa^E08  449515402   FY2001  6642000     United States   USA 1
EFT_pa^E08  NaN         FY2000  12161000    United States   USA 1
EFT_pa^E08  NaN         FY1999


MSFT.OQ     594918104   FY2019  55252000000 United States   USA 1
MSFT.OQ     594918104   FY2018  44501000000 United States   USA 1
MSFT.OQ     594918104   FY2017  42730000000 United States   USA 1
MSFT.OQ     594918104   FY2016  25145000000 United States   USA 1
EFT_pa^E08  449515402   FY2001  6642000     United States   USA 1
EFT_pa^E08  449515402   FY2000  12161000    United States   USA 1
EFT_pa^E08  449515402   FY1999
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html#pandas-dataframe-ffill) - To fill NA/NaN values using the specified forward method.

```
>>> df.ffill()
            0            1       2             3       4       5    6    7
0     MSFT.OQ  594918104.0  FY2019  5.525200e+10  United  States  USA  1.0
1     MSFT.OQ  594918104.0  FY2018  4.450100e+10  United  States  USA  1.0
2     MSFT.OQ  594918104.0  FY2017  4.273000e+10  United  States  USA  1.0
3     MSFT.OQ  594918104.0  FY2016  2.514500e+10  United  States  USA  1.0
4  EFT_pa^E08  449515402.0  FY2001  6.642000e+06  United  States  USA  1.0
5  EFT_pa^E08  449515402.0  FY2000  1.216100e+07  United  States  USA  1.0
6  EFT_pa^E08  449515402.0  FY1999  1.216100e+07  United  States  USA  1.0
```